# Moving processed data into another folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, move-semantics, shutil

So I am trying to move some pre-processed data into the proper folder as my other code isn't outputting it in the right place (asked on another question and something I am working on) and I keep having trouble. My code is posted below. I keep getting this error (posted below). I am very close, but I need the code to search one directory down to get to the files. It seems to be looking in my subject_dir instead of my dti_dir (even though I specified this in the code). I think I may just be incorrectly typing the path in for my shutil.move command. Maybe I need to join the abspath with src? If so I am unsure of the proper syntax. I am very new to coding again so I apologize if this is a trivial question!

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/gandg/infinite/imaging_data/individuals/inf0117/1/dtifit_L1.nii.gz'
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is

1. Find all files in src with "dtifit_" in their title
2. Move all of these files into dst

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions and please excuse any rookie errors as I am pretty new to coding and trying to learn!

```
# Import modules

import _utilities as util
import os
from nipype.interfaces import fsl
import shutil

# Environment and shortcuts

subject_dir = os.getcwd()
dti_dir = os.path.abspath( os.path.join(subject_dir, 'dti'))
output_path     = '../dti/dtifit'
output_basename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dti_dir, output_path))

# Move Data

src = dti_dir
dst = output_basename
print('src')
print(src)
print('dst')
print(dst)
files = os.listdir(src)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("dtifit_")):
        shutil.move(os.path.abspath((f), dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I knew the answer to my own question so I will post it here to help anyone else in a similar situation. I was right I needed to join my src with my f, but my () had been placed incorrectly the first few times I tried it so be aware of that if you are running into errors. I apologize if this question wasted the time of the more experienced coders here!

```
for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("dtifit_")):
        shutil.move(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(src,f)), dst)
```